# Reactivity not working in an object in nuxt3?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I have a nuxt page in which I am trying to change an entire nested object picked from a json file

```
import data1 from '\~/static/file1.json';
import data2 from '\~/static/file2.json';

export default {
  
    data(){
      return {
       elements:\[\],
    
      };
    },
 
    async mounted () {
      try {
        this.elements=data1;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error loading data:', error);
    }
    },
  
    methods:{
      loadData(input){
        if (input=='data1'){
          this.elements=data2
        }
        else if (input=='data2'){
        this.elements=data1
        }
      },
    }
};
```

Data in the elements variable is getting accessed in different components inside template. `loadData()` is triggered through a click event. On changing elements object completely in `loadData()` method, if the keys are different in `data2`, the changes are getting reflected on the frontend; but if the keys are same, I am not seeing any changes in dictionary values of data on the frontend. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you please give us an example of 1) the JSON objects you're working with and 2) the template portion of this component that's rendering the "elements"?